# AzureAD SSO using nodejs application

Tags: azure-active-directory, appsource

I am trying to implement azureAD single sign-on using my nodejs application. 
I have created my multi tenant app using app registration from dashboard and using WORK/SCHOOL account i tried to login but got this error

> error = access_denied
>       error_description = AADSTS65005: Using application 'Talscout-Live' is currently not supported for your organization enfintechnologies.com
>   because it is in an unmanaged state. An administrator needs to claim
>   ownership of the company by  DNS validation of enfintechnologies.com
>   before the application Talscout-Live can be provisioned.
>       Trace ID: e35xx262-dbx0-4xc4-9xx7-c6b16dbdxx00
>       Correlation ID:604xx130-6ax4-4x08-bxxd-dfb5bxx5e948

But my admin account can login without issues, not to other work/school accounts (hope business account).
I am using v1 endpoints since appsource intention id to  support only business account.

Comment: Based on the error, could you double-check that the DNS is setup correctly to verify the domain ownership? The admin might be allowed to log in since, well, otherwise they would be unable to fix the problem :D

Comment: how to check that the DNS is setup correctly to verify the domain ownership.Also i want multi tenant functionality, so whoever try to login i need to add each domain? how can i handle it?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/add-custom-domain the documentation is your friend here :)

Comment: @juunas  i want a multi-tenant application.!! so the user's domain/subdomain will be different. so how can i?

Comment: Judging from the error, there is a problem in the user tenant's DNS configuration. If this is a multi-tenant app and another tenant's user is getting that, then there is nothing you can do :/ it could of course be something else too.. But judging from the error message it looks like a DNS problem

Comment: Well, of course you should tell the tenant admin that they should check into the problem

Comment: so please tell how can i rectify the error?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167339/discussion-between-deepdil-s-and-juunas).